# sqlalchemy - connect to teradata

Tags: sqlalchemy, teradata

Sorry in advance, I am very new to Python. I am trying to connect to a Teradata database via python sqlalchemy, however I can't successfully establish a connection.

The error message I receive is "NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata".

Here is what I have so far:

```
import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'myusername'
pasw= 'mypassword'
host = 'hostname.com'
db = 'PRD_DB_SCHEMA'
engine_str = ("teradata://"+user+":"+pasw+"@"+host+":22/"+db+"?authentication=LDAP")
td_engine = create_engine(engine_str)
conn = td_engine.connect()
```

Answer (score 4):

For teradatasql, set `logmech` instead of `authentication`:

```
teradatasql://{user}:{password}@{host}/?logmech=LDAP?driver=teradata
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy/

**EDIT**: Actually, `driver` is not necessary:

```
teradatasql://{user}:{password}@{host}/?logmech=LDAP
```

Comment: In teradatasqlalchemy 17.20.0.0 it's like: teradatasql://host/?user=guest&password=please&logmech=LDAP. Reference: https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy/#Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just solved this:

```
engine_str = ("teradata://"+user+":"+pasw+"@"+host+"/?authentication=LDAP?driver=Teradata")
```